# Tcp listener AcceptTCPClientAsync exiting the while loop without error

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am writing a tcp listener to save each connection into a file

the code come as follow:

```
using NDesk.Options;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Command.Socket
{
    public class Socket
    {
        public Socket()
        {
            Port = 4380;
        }
        int Port { get; set; }
        public async void RunServerAsync()
        {

            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
            listener.Start();
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Accept(await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
                    //Console.WriteLine("ha!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Stop();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        private async Task Accept(TcpClient client)
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            try
            {
                using (client)
                using (NetworkStream n = client.GetStream())
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() + "text"))
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[500];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    int chunkSize = 1;
                    while (bytesRead < data.Length && chunkSize > 0)
                    {
                        bytesRead += chunkSize = await n.ReadAsync(data, bytesRead, data.Length - bytesRead);

                        Array.Reverse(data);
                        string[] sata = data.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToArray();
                        foreach (var s in sata)
                        {
                            file.Write(s);
                        }
                        file.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                        await n.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the Socket class as follow:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.RunServerAsync();
```

my problem is the code is leaving the while loop without any error or message.
if you want to test it just create a console application and create a class and use it.

Comment: logically it should work, anyway I changed the `async void` to `async Task` and used it like `socket.RunServerAsync().Wait()` and worked. i just don't get it why it's leaving the while loop

Comment: Turns out that you were not willing to cooperate and provide required information. I have deleted my answer for that reason and voted to close. It's not possible to resolve this question under these circumstances.